# What is the general form of a finite sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

I originally used: $a_0,a_1,a_2,...,a_n$ where $n$ is an integer greater than or equal to 0 but I've realized that this is actually an infinite sequence because n can go to $\infty$. How can I bound this so that this finite sequence can be as large as it needs to be but is still finite?

Comment: If $n\in\mathbb N$, this is a finite sequence.

Comment: There's a difference between a finite sequency of arbitrary length and an infinite sequence. Note that there are much fewer of the former than of the latter! The set of *finite* sequences of integers (which still contains *arbitrarily long* sequences!) is countable, while the set of *infinite* sequences is uncountable.